# Migrating a Chef server to another server

Tags: chef-infra, devops

I need to understand what all information is required to migrate a Chef server to another hosted server? 
I'm very new to Chef ,hence looking for this info..

Any help here is greatly appreciated !!

Comment: see: https://docs.chef.io/server_backup_restore.html

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the 'knife download' command.  You can download your current configuration.  It's good to have this checked into SCM of some kind as well.

You can also use the knife upload command to upload a complete repo to a new chef server.